# LinkedIn REST API Authentication

Tags: python, python-3.x, authentication, linkedin-api

I have created an app with the [LinkedIn API](https://www.linkedin.com/developers/apps). For some strange reason none of the authentication attempts work. I followed [this tutorial](https://towardsdatascience.com/mining-data-on-linkedin-9b70681b1467) based on the [Python-LinkedIn interface](https://pythonrepo.com/repo/ozgur-python-linkedin-python-third-party-apis-wrappers). I get the authentication URL to paste into a web browser but no log-in page is displayed. The error message I get from LinkedIn is not helpful, i.e. "something went wrong" (see picture).

My code so far:

```
import requests 
import string
import random


clientID = "_cID from API__"
clientSecret = "__CS from API___" #
redirect_uri = "https://wemf.ch/de/"
letters = string.ascii_lowercase
csrfToken = ''.join(random.choice(letters) for i in range(24))

html = requests.get("https://www.linkedin.com/oauth/v2/authorization",
                   params = auth_params)
print(html.url)
```

I have also tried to set the redirect URL to http://localhost:8000 as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17600244/how-to-use-linkedin-api-with-python), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51195121/accessing-linkedin-data-via-api-using-python-and-authorisation-in-general) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35370168/authentification-to-linkedin-api)

I do not use any VPN. I have tried Edge, Firefox and Chrome. They all show the same error message in the picture.

Thanks for your help.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In the mean time I have found the answer. The issue was a white space in the scopes. 
Before you run below code, check what access [scopes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/shared/authentication/getting-access) your app has and adjust below code accordingly. The code implements the [3-legged oauth flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/shared/authentication/authorization-code-flow?tabs=HTTPS) for access to the [Marketing Development Platform (MDP)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/marketing/).

**Step 1: Get the authorisation code from the URL**

```
import requests

client_id = '_your_client_ID_'
client_secret = '_your_client_secret'

base_url = "https://www.linkedin.com/oauth/v2/authorization"
redirect_uri = "https://www.linkedin.com/developers/tools/oauth/redirect"
#adjust scope. 
scope = "w_member_social,r_organization_social,w_organization_social,r_liteprofile"

url = f"{base_url}?response_type=code&client_id={client_id}&state=random&redirect_uri={redirect_uri}&scope={scope}"
print(url)

auth_code = "_copy_authorisation_code_from_the_URL"
```

--> the authorisation code is hidden in the URL displayed after you log-in to your LinkedIn account and give the app access permission. Here an example what it will look like: 
https://www.linkedin.com/developers/tools/oauth/redirect?code=___you_will_find_the_code_here___&state=random


**Step 2: Get access token**

```
url_access_token = 'https://www.linkedin.com/oauth/v2/accessToken'

payload = {
    'grant_type' : 'authorization_code',
    'code' : auth_code,
    'redirect_uri' : redirect_uri,
    'client_id' : client_id,
    'client_secret' : client_secret
}

response = requests.post(url=url_access_token, params=payload)
response_json = response.json()
# Extract the access_token from the response_json
access_token = response_json['access_token']
```

**Step 3: Get own profile data**

 *spoiler alert* - it is not much data but shows that the authorisation worked. If you want your own LinkedIn data it is easier to request it online and you'll get all of your data in 2 zip files.

```
def get_profile(access_token):
    URL = "https://api.linkedin.com/v2/me"
    headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
               'Authorization':'Bearer {}'.format(access_token),'X-Restli-Protocol-Version':'2.0.0'}
    response = requests.get(url=URL, headers=headers)
    print(response.json())

get_profile(access_token)
```